# How do I get Node.js request type?

Tags: node.js, express

I was trying to figure out how to get the request type from a node request. I want to perform different tasks based on the type.

```
module.exports = function(req, resp, next){
    if (req.type == 'GET'){
        //Do something
    }else{
        // Do else something
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the answer to what I was doing wrong. I needed to assign req to a var and compare to the var value. "var method = req"   "if (method == 'GET')"

Comment: Careful here, you are using a double equals which does type conversion underneath (i.e. `0 == "0"` would return true, despite the fact one is a number and the other a string).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`req.method` returns the request HTTP method used.

Comment: Values of `req.method`: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `OPTIONS`

Comment: The nestjs `RequestMethod` enum implementation is: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, `PATCH`, `ALL`, `OPTIONS`, `HEAD`

Answer (score 5):

```js
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  let requestMethod = req.method;
  console.log(requestMethod);
  res.send('ok');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this sample code

```
exports.permissionsCheck = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userId = req.body.auth.id;
    let permissions = await PermissionsClass.getAllPermissions(userId)

    let url = req.url
    let method = req.method

    console.log(method)

    return next();
};
```